# a/the loss of 8 wickets

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

> The Australian cricket team scored 200 runs with **the/a** loss of 8 wickets in 20 overs.

I am confused if I should use an indefinite article or the definite article in the above sentence . According to me, if we say “the loss” we mean a particular loss, and if we say “a loss”, we mean “any one loss”. But I am not able to figure out if what is suitable in this sentence because both the articles seem correct to me, “the loss” means a specific loss of 8 wickets, and we generally use “a loss” most of the time. So I am not sure what the correct article in this sentence is.

Comment: It is more usual to say _for the loss_ but _with_ is not wrong. What grammatical issue is at stake here I cannot say.

Comment: “...for a loss of 8 wickets...”, does it sound wrong?

Comment: Yes, _a loss_ is wrong here but, as I mentioned, I do not know what the grammar rule at stae here is.

Comment: Definite article "the" is used here. You can majorly hear this during a running commentary of a live cricket match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, the reader understands when the wickets occur, both

> a loss of 8 wickets

and

> the loss of 8 wickets

are acceptable.  Usually, the latter is used in commentary.